# Generate combination of singualr and plural stings using python?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have data set like below.

```
col1                      col2
cat rat                   Lion
children, geese,pantss    man
```

Here I want to take input as col1 and generate all possible combination of singular and plurals col1 values which are **Nouns** otherwise keep that string as it is and append those combinations below that particular input string and put/repeat the respective col2 value as it is.

I want output like below

```
col1                        col2
cat rat                     Lion
cat rats                    Lion
cats rat                    Lion
cats rats                   Lion

children, geese, pantss      man
children, geese, pants       man
children, goose, pantss      man
child, geese,pantss          man
child, goose,pantss          man
child, geese,pants           man
```

I have been trying below code for single value of col1 but I am not able to iterate through given input for multiple time to generate the possible combinations. Could you please anyone help how do I achieve give output. Is there any python library available.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
blob = TextBlob(df['col1'].ix[0])


sentence = blob.sentences[0]
print(sentence.tags)
print(len(sentence.tags))

main_lst = []

lst = []


for word, pos in sentence.tags:
    print(word,pos)      

    if pos == 'NNS':
        print(word.singularize())
        lst.append(word.singularize())

    elif pos == 'NN':
        lst.append(word.pluralize())
        print(lst)

    else:
        lst.append(word)

main_lst.append(lst)


df = df.append(pd.Series(main_lst, index=['c1']),ignore_index=True)

df['c1'].ix[1] = lst
df['c2'].ix[1] = df['Target'].ix[0]
```

Thanks,
Niranjan